# Can I use a PC to emulate a USB key?

Tags: windows, usb, emulation, virtual

I am testing an electronic equipment that has a USB port.
During my tests I have to juggle with different USB keys to test different features of the product (key with mp3s, key with images, mixed key, key for reflashing the product, ...).
Each test requires the physical handling of USB keys.

I would have liked to know if it is possible to connect my equipment to a Windows PC, and to emulate a USB key from this PC in order to be able to connect/disconnect virtually different keys with different contents?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a "USB key"?

Comment: They are trying to devise an automated test suite for testing various configurations of flash drives (or some other USB device) with differing arrangements of files. Off topic for this site and probably too broad to ask anyways without breaking it down to smaller workable pieces.

Comment: The OP is probably referring to USB mass storage devices.